# How to manage a user session using Azure Mobile Services?

Tags: session, authentication, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm building mobile applications using .NET. What I'm looking for is a way to manage user sessions and info using Azure Mobile Services. I've read a lot about the authentication in Azure Mobile Services, but this only authenticates a user via Facebook, Twitter, etc ... to access azure services.

I'm looking for user session management, i.e. register, login, logout. Be able to save and retrieve user info, i.e., save certain info against the user such as age for example. Also session management and caching, i.e. the user will remain logged on when the app is closed and re-opened. Also azure mobile services doesn't seem to provide a way to allow me to register users via email.

Basically, If anyone is familiar with [Parse](https://parse.com/), I'm looking for having similar functionality in Azure. Can anyone help please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Out of the box, Mobile Services provides easy authentication with social providers (Facebook, Twitter, etc) and Azure Active Directory.  If you want to do registration via email, you'll have to create a custom auth system.  This is going to be more complex than just flipping a switch and using Facebook auth, but totally doable and I can point you in the right direction.  First, check out [this post](http://chrisrisner.com/Custom-Authentication-with-Azure-Mobile-Services-and-LensRocket) that will explain how you can create a registration / login system using custom API and the script backend.  If you're using a .NET backend, you'll need to alter thing a bit (the samples are in JS) but it should be pretty easy to convert.  The only piece that is really missing from that post is how to do email verification.  To do this with Mobile Services, I would suggest the following.

1. Sign up for a SendGrid account (free in the Azure store)
2. From your script, after registering the user, generate a random alphanumeric string that is saved to their account / user record in the table.
3. Use the same string to create a URL which you can send to the user's email address (check out [this tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/store-sendgrid-mobile-services-send-email-scripts/) for sending email via SendGrid and Mobile Services).
4. The link can either go to a different custom API or a web front end.  When that endpoint is hit, it should update the user record to show that they have verified their email address.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer. I'll check it and get back to you.